# Hibernate one-to-many foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

In the hbm file, I added:

```
<set cascade="all-delete-orphan" fetch="join" inverse="true" lazy="false" name="employeeTrainings" table="employee_training" >
  <key>
    <column name="employeeid" not-null="true"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="net.talaco.hr.db.model.EmployeeTraining"/>
</set>
```

to map the set in my java class:

```
private Set employeeTrainings = new HashSet(0);
```

However, When I add objects to my Set setting all the fields (foreign keys), it seems that hibernate is not saving my object (the relation) and I get the exception: `employee_id` does not have a default value. employee_id is set actually.
I am using `saveOrUpdate` to save my Parent object.